# Check if element with data attribute equal to value exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a huge problem with verification if among of elements is a one which has data attribute equal to another value.

The HTML code is like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
<li data-img="1">Demo</li>
<li data-img="2">Demo</li>
<li data-img="3">Demo</li>
<li data-img="4">Demo</li>
</ul>

<div class="banners">
<img src="........." data-img="1"/>
<img src="........." data-img="2"/>
<img src="........." data-img="4"/>
</div>
```

The JS code is like this:

```
$('.menu li').each(function(){
$(this).hover(function(){
var el = $(this).attr('data-img');
var el2 = $('.banners').find('[data-img=' + el + ']'); 

// or maybe it should be: 
var el2 = $('.banners').attr('data-img');

// Here I would like to check if el2 equals to el exists add to this element (el2) the class name "foo"

}, function(){
});
});
```

I'm dunno if I should replace all in

Comment: First I suggest you to care more the indentation and to add the `//` when you add comment into your code, this will help all developers to figure out the problem. The solution you should use is the one with `find`, as the second one will return the value of attribute `data-img` of first element in the page with class `banners`.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, I added correction. Ok, now I used find method, but still I don't know how to verify if this element exists.

Comment: You wouldnt need to check if that element exists. You can select an element, as mentioned above and then just append  `.addClass('foo');` so you get `$('.banners').find('[data-img=' + el + ']').addClass('foo')` jQuery is smart enough not to make you troubles if no element exists that matches your selector

Comment: I agree with @Lapskaus, you can also add a small shortcut: `$('.banners [data-img="'+el+'"]').addClass('foo');`. Also, please care more the indentation when you push your code for other developers.

Comment: I need check it because I want reset class "foo" for others images if el2 exists (I mean current hover element), but if not exists the class "foo" should be in the last image which has attribute equals to el. That's why I have a problem.

Comment: Same thing here, you do not need to know if that element exists, just remove the class `foo` on all $('.banners [data-img"]') elements. See the answer of Nick

Comment: Thank you guys for all suggestions, matthias_h solution works perfect for me, that's all what I really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reset the class "foo" for other images if el2 exists and, if it not exists, the class "foo" should be in the last image which has the `data-img` attribute equal to el, you can do it like this:

```js
$('.menu li').each(function() {
  $(this).hover(function() {
      var el = $(this).attr('data-img');
      var el2 = $('.banners').find('[data-img=' + el + ']');
      if (el2.length) {
        let images = $('.banners img');
        images.each(function() {
          $(this).removeClass('foo');
        });
        el2.addClass('foo');
      }
    },
    function() {});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li data-img="1">Demo</li>
  <li data-img="2">Demo</li>
  <li data-img="3">Demo</li>
  <li data-img="4">Demo</li>
  <li data-img="5">Demo</li>
</ul>

<div class="banners">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" data-img="1" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" data-img="2" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" data-img="3" />
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff" data-img="4" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you matthias_h - that's all what I really needed.

Comment: @yanca Glad that I was able to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know whether the element exists; you can simply `addClass` to the result of the selector and if there are no matches to the selector nothing will happen. In the `mouseleave` part you `removeClass` from the same image:

```js
$('.menu li').each(function() {
  $(this).hover(function() {
      var el = $(this).attr('data-img');
      $('.banners').find('[data-img=' + el + ']').addClass('foo');
    },
    function() {
      var el = $(this).attr('data-img');
      $('.banners').find('[data-img=' + el + ']').removeClass('foo');
    });
});
```

```css
img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.foo {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
  <li data-img="1">Demo</li>
  <li data-img="2">Demo</li>
  <li data-img="3">Demo</li>
  <li data-img="4">Demo</li>
</ul>

<div class="banners">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF" data-img="1" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/00FF00" data-img="2" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000" data-img="4" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
$('.menu li').each(function(){
  $(this).hover(function(){
     let img = $(this).data('img');
     let bannerImg = $('.banners').find(`img[data-img="${img}"]`);
     if (bannerImg.length) {
       bannerImg.addClass('foo');
     }
  }, function() {
     let img = $(this).data('img');
     let bannerImg = $('.banners').find(`img[data-img="${img}"]`);
     if (bannerImg.length) {
       bannerImg.removeClass('foo');
     }
  });
});
```

Hopefully, It will work.